# Restore deleted directory that was never committed

Tags: git, restore

I accidentally added a local directory to my local Git repo.

```
git add dirName
```

It added the twenty or so files in that directory.  I did not want them added.  They had never been added before, and I did not commit them.  Instead, I removed them with:

```
git rm -rf dirName
```

This successfully removed them from the repo, but to my dismay that directory also appears to have been deleted from disk.  They are not in my recycle bin.

Is there any way to get those files back?  I have a backup, of course, but I had made quite a few changes to the files since the last backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no there isn't because

```
git rm -rf dirName
```

is like

```
rm -rf dirName
```

which is also irreversible but it also removes the staging files so there is no way you can get the files back. Next time use git rm --cached dirName which will only remove it from stage and not from your disc.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the accepted answer is entirely accurate. Indeed `git rm` removes the files from the index, but they usually remain in Git's object database for a while. Unless you force garbage collection, that is.

Have you tried running `git fsck` to retrieve some *dangling blobs* or *dangling trees* ?

```
$ git init test
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/DOCUME~1/T012345/LOCALS~1/Temp/test/.git/

$ echo baz > foo/bar.txt

$ git add -Av
add 'foo/bar.txt'

$ git rm -rf *
rm 'foo/bar.txt'

$ git fsck
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
dangling blob 76018072e09c5d31c8c6e3113b8aa0fe625195ca

$ git cat-file -p 76018072e09c5d31c8c6e3113b8aa0fe625195ca
baz
```

Comment: this should be the real answer

Comment: this is correct for a file but the question is for a directory. For a directory it will not work, cause you would have to know the directory structure.